# How to delete a particular line from a file

Tags: c, file-io

```
ex: roll_no  name subject
       10       aa    ss
       20       bb    tt
       30       cc    uu
       40       dd    vv
```

If I have a file and it is containing some record in every line, then how to delete           that particular line. EX: like a student record and key is roll no, `if key==roll` no(read from file) then *delete* it.

Comment: No they are different, i have already read them.

Comment: Record size is fixed, to be able to calculate the row position by the key, you can do it removed by rewriting the key.

Comment: No i did not tried actually. I am searching for the simplest way to do it otherwise I have some different idea but that is complicated.